# How To make an icon appearing on hovering a Node in TreeTable using Jide

Tags: java, swing, jide

It would be helpful to know while using TreeTable from JideTable. How to make a label or button appearing on the tree nodes only if the mouse is hovered?

Comment: Do you want a tooltip or do you want to change the the actual node itself

Comment: not a tool tip just a button should come along the tree node so the user can move along and click for the event

Comment: @MadProgrammer did u got any solutions on this??

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JideTable`, but I would suggest, you will need to add a component to it, but you'd need to provide the coordinates and size for the component when you do so as it's likely not to be using a layout

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the possible Info.. but making a pop up like panel with milli second duration of display will nurture the design